# What software programs are recommended for background extraction and peak fitting?

Tags: resource-recommendations, spectroscopy, statistics, software, data-analysis

I have an energy spectrum for various gamma sources. What software programs are recommended for background extraction and peak fitting in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommendations posted will depend on who is using the software already. Some commonly recommended commercial software for what you ask include the following:

[Origin](https://www.originlab.com) - widely used but general purpose (must roll your own routines)

[Igor Pro](https://www.wavemetrics.com) - great to generate publication-ready graphics (must roll your own routines)

[SigmaPlot](https://systatsoftware.com/downloads/download-sigmaplot/) - general purpose

[PeakFit](http://www.alfasoft.com/en/products/statistics-and-analysis/139-peakfit-en.html) - dedicated solely to peak fitting (less emphasis on quality of results than e.g. Igor Pro)

[Matlab](https://www.matlab.com), and specifically the [Curve Fitting Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/curvefitting.html). Gives you a lot of diagnostics on fit quality and such.

[Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) - general computing system that has a wide array of fitting functions.

Some freeware include the following:

[Fityk](https://fityk.nieto.pl) - focused on a specific set of peak fitting options

[MagicPlot](https://magicplot.com) - a lightweight app for general non-linear regression fitting

[Peak-O-Mat](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lorentz/) - touts its utility for batch fitting of spectra

[Python with SciPy](https://www.scipy.org/) - very general library that includes [curve fitting utilities](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).

You can find some reviews (and other random recommendations) at these links:

[arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04362) -- specifically about analysis of gamma spectra

[ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Professional_peak_fitting_software_for_spectral_data_analysis) - reviews of general peak fitting in spectrscopy

[WindowsReport](https://windowsreport.com/curve-fitting-software-windows-10/) - reviews of curve fitting software for Windows

Answer (score 0):

for that you can use for example "Origin" or you can look if there is a python library, which does that for you, since Origin costs money.

https://plot.ly/python/peak-fitting/

https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_bg_subtraction/py_bg_subtraction.html